# Is it possible to auto fix orientation from images without EXIF information?

Tags: image, orientation, carrierwave, exif, minimagick

I have an Ubuntu server which auto corrects images according to their orientation. The problem is that some pictures uploaded by users doesnt necessarily have EXIF info. Is it possible to handle this case?

Note: I currently use Rails CarrierWave::MiniMagick to rotate images on the server, like this 'img.tap(&:auto_orient)' and it works fine for pictures with EXIF info.